# Can't scrape some data out of a table in a customized way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse tabular content out of some html elements and arrange them in customized manner so that I can write them accordingly in a csv file later.

The table looks almost exactly like ***[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytzcw.jpg)***.

Html elements are like (truncated):

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" class="header">ATLANTIC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="black10bold">Facility</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Type</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Funding</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJ60104"> Complete Care at Linwood, LLC </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJ60102">The Health Center At Galloway</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" class="header">BERGEN</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="black10bold">Facility</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Type</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Funding</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=30201">The Actors Fund Homes</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJAL02007"> Actors Fund Home, The </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried so far:

```
for item in soup.select("tr"):
    try:
        header = item.select_one("td.header").text
    except AttributeError:
        header = ""
    try:
        item_name = item.select_one("td > a").text
    except AttributeError:
        item_name = ""
    print(item_name,header)
```

Output it produces:

```
ATLANTIC
 
Complete Care at Linwood, LLC  
The Health Center At Galloway 

 BERGEN
 
The Actors' Fund Homes
Actors Fund Home, The
```

Output I would like to have:

```
Complete Care at Linwood, LLC  ATLANTIC
The Health Center At Galloway  ATLANTIC
The Actors' Fund Homes         BERGEN
Actors Fund Home, The          BERGEN
```

Comment: could you also provide an url your requesting, please?

Comment: Sharing url won't help as I had to made few post http requests to reach the content I pasted above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce the output the way you wanted to have.

```
for item in soup.select("tr"):
    if item.select_one("td.header"):
        header = item.select_one("td.header").text

    elif item.select_one("td > a"):
        item_name = item.select_one("td > a").text
        print(item_name,header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope its help you.

```
import os
import csv
html = """<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" class="header">ATLANTIC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="black10bold">Facility</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Type</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Funding</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJ60104"> Complete Care at Linwood, LLC </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJ60102">The Health Center At Galloway</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" class="header">BERGEN</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="black10bold">Facility</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Type</td>
    <td class="black10bold">Funding</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=30201">The Actors Fund Homes</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 55%">
        <a href="fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=NJAL02007"> Actors Fund Home, The </a>
    </td>
</tr>"""



soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
output_rows = []
for table_row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

print(output_rows)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```